# Parse XML with JSTL

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jstl

I am trying to get only first record from loop, Or how can I stop this loop after first record?

```
<x:parse var="taggedData" xml="${taggedLoad}"/>
<x:forEach var="item" select="$taggedData//item" varStatus="status">
    <h4>
        <a href="/go/video/index.jsp?videoId=<str:substring start="5"><x:out select="$item/guid"/></str:substring>" onclick="javascript:loadBCvideo(<str:substring start="5"><x:out select="$item/guid"/></str:substring>); return false;"><x:out select="$item/title" /></a>
    </h4>
    <p>
         <x:out select="$item/description" escapeXml="false" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//*[local-name()='item'])[position() &lt;= 1]">
```

or:

```
def result = records.children().find {
    domain -> domain.@domain_name == targetDomain
}

result.children().each {
    // do stuff
}
```